# Where to free the memory allocated in functions overloading operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

I was trying to learn basic C++ operator overloading concepts. I have a class mystring and related code as shown below. In functions used to overload '+' operator, where can I free the memory to avoid memory leaks.

```
#include <iostream>


class mystring
{
    char *ptr;

    public:

   mystring(char *str = "")
   {
      ptr = new char[strlen(str) + 1]
      strcpy(ptr,str);

   } 

   mystring operator +(mystring s)
   {
      char *str = new char[strlen(ptr) + strlen(s.ptr) + 1];//where should this memory be freed
      strcpy(str,ptr);
      strcat(str,s.ptr);
      return mystring v1(str);
   }
   ~mystring()
   {
      delete [] ptr; 
   }
};

int main()
{
   mystring a="Hello",b="World",c;

  c = a + b;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
   mystring operator +(mystring s) 
   { 
      char *str = new char[strlen(ptr) + strlen(s.ptr) + 1];//where should this memory be freed 
      strcpy(str,ptr); 
      strcat(str,s.ptr); 
      mystring v1(str);
      delete[] str;
      return v1
   }
```

Or have a private constructor

```
MyStr(char *str, bool dummy)
{
   ptr =  str;
}
```

then

```
....strcat().
   mystring v1(str, false);
   return v1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your concatenation operator is going to have the same problems as assignment operators so this will be a useful read: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/assignment-operators.html

- Allocate memory for the new larger string, strcpy/cat into it, delete the old str pointer's memory, then assign the member str to point to the newly created larger string

Answer (score 0):

Memory should be freed in the destructor of mystring, but you will need to rethink your design a bit.

```
mystring operator +(mystring s)
{
    mystring result;
    result.ptr = new char[strlen(ptr) + strlen(s.ptr) + 1];

    strcpy(result.ptr,ptr);
    strcat(result.ptr,s.ptr);
    return result;
}
```

Note you need a default constructor to create an empty string. Besides you will have to handle the ptr resource adding a proper copy-constructor, an assignment operator and a destructor. Besides that, you should be taking your parameter by const&. Furthermore, the + operator is better implemented as a free function; either as a friend or based in a member += operator.

Comment: If the pointer was a data member and which is allocated, then destructor would have access to the pointer o free it, but here the pointer which is allocated using new, is inside operator overloading function , so how would destructor have access to it to free it?

Comment: Think how will you free the memory allocated in mystring constructor, meanwhile I will update my answer with some code.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the point of the exercise is just to learn. I would avoid creating a string type like this in real life. Now back to the original problem, the solution is to always use RAII for management of resources, and that can be done in different ways, but one of the simplest one is using the *copy-and-swap* together with the *rule of the three* (I wrote about that just a couple of days ago [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/09/rule-of-3-4-swap.html) Using RAII to manage the resources means *at all times* means that you do not need think too hard on how and when you have to release them.